# Overwrite input field after using preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have used the following code

```
$('#id1').keypress(function(e){
if ($('#mail_mobNumber').val().length > 9) {
e.preventDefault();
});
```

So, if I enter 10 numbers, I cannot enter anything more, and that is the goal.
But, on the other hand, after I enter 10 digits and if I select the entire field using Control + A, and tries to enter something, instead of the text getting replaced by what I am entering, nothing happens.
I understand that it is due to the impact of the above code, but is there anyway to achieve this, that is, allowing me to overwriting input after pressing Control + A.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the `maxlength` attribute in the `input` tag instead.

```html
<input type="email" maxlength="10">
```

Comment: I am sorry, I should have mentioned this before. The input is dependent on other things. Example, a certain country has a phone number of a certain number of digits, so this stops us from directly putting the maxlength inside the html tag.

Comment: If you want to change the input's max-length,  just do `$('#input').attr('maxlength', newLength);`

Comment: okay, that is helpful, thank you. but I have used preventDefault() to limit more than just length, so in general is there anyway to override it?